# Rails 5 load HTML from a remote URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5, on the server side, thus without using Ajax/jQuery and without using iFrames, can I load HTML from a **remote domain** in to a view?

For example, in my view home.html.erb I would like to do something similar to:

```
<div id="remote_content">
  <%= render "https://www.example.com/index.html" %>
</div>
```

I know I could use Ajax for this, but since it is a remote domain, I get in to cross-domain issues.

Comment: What about `<iframe>` tags?

Comment: I've updated the question to say "without using iframes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
Here is what worked for me. Thanks to @court3ney for suggesting using ajax to my own controller and then use an http library in the controller. I decided on using HTTParty.

**CoffeeScript**

```
user_id = $('#user_id').text()
$("#widget").load('/users/' + user_id + '/widget')
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  ...
end

def widget
  @user = User.find(params[:id])      
  @widget = HTTParty.get('https://www.example.com/widget.html?user=@user.id', timeout: 10) 
  render :layout => 'blank'
end
```

**Show View**

```
...
<div id="widget"></div>
...
```

**Widget View**

```
<%= raw(@widget) %>
```

**Routes**

```
  get 'users/:id/widget' => 'users#widget'
```

Comment: This will freeze your page while it loads and break your site while it's down, so i recommend a few things; use a http library with a timeout, and also,  put just that 'open' line in a new controller action that you call with ajax. So then your page always loads!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion using Ajax on my own controller. That should get around the cross domain issue. Any suggestion on a better http library?

Comment: something like this

Comment: net/http with a timeout, ```Net::HTTP.start(host, port, :open_timeout => 5, :read_timeout => 5) do |http|
  http.request(...)
end```

Answer (score -1):

Use an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/index.html"></iframe>
```

[w3c docs on iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp)

Comment: I was hoping to not use an iframe due to iframe limitations, but to instead inject the received html directly in to the page via Rails on the server side.